# Laravel + Vuejs: How to link image to Laravel Public folder

Tags: laravel, vue.js

This is what I used before when I was using blade.

```php
<img src="{{ asset('images/3379.svg') }}" alt="computer">
```

But now that I am using vue, it does not work anymore.

How do we link to public/asset folder in vuejs?

Comment: Have you considered using proxies in vue.config.js?

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

#1 Create an alias in webpack.config.js. Add this `'@assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')` line of code.

webpack.config.js

```java
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve('resources/js'),
            '@assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
        },
    },
};
```

#2 Load config to webpack.mix.js. Add these lines of code:

```java
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');
mix.webpackConfig(webpackConfig);
```

#3 Use the alias
`<img src='@assets/images/3379.svg' alt="computer"/>`

[Reference]
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/javascript/how-to-shortcut-the-path-to-the-assets-directory-in-vuejs-spa